Help about solution verfication of a problem : Prove that there exists a player with at most q wins
I need some help to verify if my attempt of solution to the following problem is correct.
The problem statement is as follow :
In a round-robin tournament with $n$ players, each player plays every other player exactly once, and each match results in a win for one player and a loss for the other. When player $A$ defeats player $B$, we call $B$ the victim of $A$. At the end of the tournament, each player computes the total number of losses incurred by the player's victims. Let $q$ be the average of this quantity over all players. Prove that there exists a player with at most $\lfloor q \rfloor$ wins and a player with at most $\lfloor q \rfloor$ losses
Attempt here:
Step 1: Understanding the Quantities Involved:
For each player $i$, let:
$w_i$ denote the number of wins by player $i$.
$l_i = n-1-w_i $ denote the number of losses by player $ i$.
$ L_i $ denote the total number of losses incurred by the victims of player $ i $.
Thus, $L_i$ is given by:
$$
L_i = \sum_{j \in S_i} \ell_j,
$$
where $S_i$ is the set of players that player $i$ has defeated.
Step 2: Analyzing the Total Sum $\sum_{i=1}^n L_i $
Let us compute the sum of all $L_i$:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n L_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \in S_i} \ell_j.
$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n L_i=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{i \text { beat } j} \cdot \ell_j = \sum_{j=1}^{n} l_{j}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{i \text { beat } j} $$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n L_i = \sum_{j=1}^n l_j  (n-1 -w_{j}) =\sum_{j=1}^{n} (n-1-w_{j})^{2} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_{j}^{2}
$$
as $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} w_{j} = \binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Did I maid any error in the computations ?

Step 3: Analyzing the Average $q$

From Here I need help  to check if the following is correct

The average $q$ is given by:
$$
q = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n L_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n w_j^2 
$$
We know that the total number of wins  in the tournament is:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n w_j = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
$$
Step 4: Back to the problem
For $n\geq 5$.
For the shake of contradiction, suppose that for all player  we have either $w_{i}> q$ or $l_{i}> q$.
By Cauchy-Schwarz :
$$n \cdot nq \geq  (\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i})^{2}=\frac{n^{2} \cdot (n-1)^{2}}{4} $$
Hence
$$q \geq \frac{(n-1)^{2}}{4} $$
but $q < w_{i} \leq w_{i}+l_{i}=n-1$
and so   :
$$\frac{(n-1)^{2}}{4} \leq q < (n-1)$$
we get :
$n-1 < 4$ so $n\leq 4$ which is a contradiction.
It remais to check the cases for $n\in\{2,3,4\}$.
Source of the problem : Art of Problem Solving, "Prove that there exists a player with at most $\left\lceil q \right\rceil$ wins"

Where did you encounter this problem?  I encourage you to credit the original source.  Note that we require proper attribution for all material copied from other sources: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Please review the guidance at https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info and revise your question accordingly. Note that questions of the form "here is a problem, here is my attempted solution, is my solution correct?" are not a good fit here.

Sorry added problem source it was on Aops, I proposed a solution but didn’t receive any review, from the autor, found the problem very interesting, gave me a new interpretation of the quadratic mean, If my computations are correct… That’s why I am looking for a review …

Thanks.  It helps if you include some keywords, like the name of the forum and the title of the post, to make it easier for others with the same question to find this via search. Also it would be better to link directly to the problem statement, rather than to your proposed solution/response.

Also, this still doesn't comply with the guidelines regarding solution verification questions.  Please revise the question to comply with those guidelines.

Sorry I don’t understand well what you need me to do, would you kindly link me an example of good formulation. My english is not fluent.

TL;DR It looks correct for $n\geq 5$.
We can independently verify fairly far down into Step 2 by observing that the amount each player contributes to $\sum_i L_i$ is equal to their number of losses times the number they lost against, so $\sum_iL_i=\sum_il_i^2$.
The fact that $\sum_il_i^2=\sum_i(n-1-w_i)^2=\sum_iw_i^2$ is unintuitive, but it does follow since
$$\sum_i(n-1)^2-2\sum_i(n-1)w_i=n(n-1)^2-2(n-1)\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=0$$
My Cauchy-Schwarz is admittedly a little rusty, but your expression compares favorably to this form of the inequality. I was able to get
$$nq=\sum_iw_i^2\geq\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_iw_i\right)^2$$
One minor nit: you've assumed either $\forall i,w_i>q$ or $\forall i,l_i>q$, and it looks like you just used the former in your argument instead of the disjunction. But it doesn't really constitute a problem, since the same argument holds for $l_i>q$.
As for how to prove for $n\in\{2,3,4\}$, it's probably easiest to verify manually on each distribution of wins (as you've shown, only $w_i$ is needed to calculate $q$ ; who loses to whom doesn't matter). For this, the win distributions are
$$n=2: (1,0)\\
n=3: (2,1,0),\ (1,1,1)\\
n=4: (3,2,1,0),\ (3,1,1,1),\ (2,2,2,0),\ (2,2,1,1)$$

Thank you for you help, really appreciated. I don’t know why the reward button doesn’t work even tho I accepted your answer

@uvw if you mean the bounty, I think it makes you wait the full 7 days to give everyone a fair shake at answering the question best
